# Server-side datatable processing but data not showing

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datatable

Currently trying to get a server-side datatable working with C# and MVC. 
I've gotten to the point where the data is being return from the service using the ajax call in javascript, but the datatable stays processing...

[image]

And the return data looks good too:

[image]
Javascript:

```
var accountTable = $("#accountTable").DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: '/Entity/AjaxGetJsonData?entityId=' + $("#AdviserId").val(),
        type: "GET",
        columns: [
            { "data": "Date", "orderable": true },
            { "data": "OtherEntity", "orderable": false },
            { "data": "Description", "orderable": false },
            {
                "sDefaultContent": "",
                "sClass": "dtAlignRight",
                "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                    if (row.Amount.charAt(1) == '-') {
                        var negativeAmount = row.Amount.slice(2);
                        return "-$" + negativeAmount;
                    }
                    else {
                        return row.Amount;
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        success: function (msg) {
            //do something here
        }
    }
});
```

C# Return data:

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult AjaxGetJsonData(int entityId, int draw)
    {
        List<TransactionView> transactions = CommissionService.GetDefaultTransactions(entityId);
        List<DataItem> items = TransformToDataItem(transactions);
        string search = Request.QueryString["search[value]"];
        int sortColumn = -1;
        //string sortDirection = "asc";
        if (Request.QueryString["order[0][column]"] != null)
        {
            sortColumn = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["order[0][column]"]);
        }
        DataTableData table = new DataTableData();
        table.draw = draw;
        table.recordsTotal = items.Count;
        table.data = items;
        table.recordsFiltered = items.Count;

        return Json(table, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Other relevant stuff:

```
public List<DataItem> TransformToDataItem(List<TransactionView> transactions)
{
    List<DataItem> results = new List<DataItem>();
    foreach (TransactionView view in transactions)
    {
        DataItem item = new DataItem();
        item.Date = view.Date;
        item.OtherEntity = view.OtherEntity.Trim();
        item.Description = view.Description.Trim();
        item.Amount = view.Amount;
        results.Add(item);
    }
    return results;
}

public class DataItem
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string OtherEntity {get; set;}
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
}

public class DataTableData
{
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public int recordsTotal { get; set; }
    public int recordsFiltered { get; set; }
    public List<DataItem> data { get; set; }
}
```

Is there something that I am missing that is causing the datatable to always be processing and never populates the table with the data?

Comment: I don't think `columns` is supposed to be inside of `ajax`

Comment: agreed silly mistake.Thanks dave

Comment: You might find it helpful to use my wrapper library for Datatables: http://aspdatatables.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Columns` should be a child of `DataTable`, not of `ajax`. Also, the `success` is probably unnecessary. See the examples in the [reference](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax)

```
var accountTable = $("#accountTable").DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: '/Entity/AjaxGetJsonData?entityId=' + $("#AdviserId").val(),
        type: "GET"
    },
    columns: [
         { "data": "Date", "orderable": true },
         { "data": "OtherEntity", "orderable": false },
         { "data": "Description", "orderable": false },
         {
              "sDefaultContent": "",
              "sClass": "dtAlignRight",
              "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                    if (row.Amount.charAt(1) == '-') {
                         var negativeAmount = row.Amount.slice(2);
                         return "-$" + negativeAmount;
                    }
                    else {
                         return row.Amount;
                    }
              }
         }
    ]

});
```

Comment: Ah. Perfect. A silly childish mistake hahaha. Wows i would've never picked up on that hahaha. It's been a long day. Thanks very much David :)